# Is there a way to hide the definition of a SQL Server stored procedure from a SQL admin?

Tags: sql, sql-server, security, stored-procedures, encryption

I've been asked to hide the definition of several SQL Server stored procedures and initially looked at the WITH ENCRYPTION option but from what I can tell a fellow admin can simply decrypt this.

Is there anyway to hide the definition even from other admins with sa privileges?

Comment: This sounds like a people issue rather than a technical one - If you can't trust the people that you've given sa rights to on a server, you shouldn't have given them sa rights in the first place.

Comment: Its a vendor database, to support us the need admin rights , however we are quite certain they are copying our stored procs and views and adding to their product. So we need the support but don't want our IP stolen (its our competitive advantage). hence we are looking for a technical solution to a people problem. We could deal with this from a people perspective, legal,or possibly something else but would prefer a technical solution.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way.

If you are a member of the sysadmin role, you can decrypt the sql modules easily, for example by using this tool: https://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/sqldecryptor/

It needs access to one of two things:

1. The Dedicated Admin Connection
2. DBCC PAGE

A sysadmin has access to both. Even if you explicitly deny their use, they can just re-grant themselves.

However, you can audit their use. Once you have that setup, the rest is a matter of the contract between you and the vendor. If you set this up correctly (ask your lawyer), they should have no incentive to even try.